# qt widgets are overlapping when added to another widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget

**Okay so I have done some debugging. I wrote a code to display my QFrame on another QFrame in a simple layout manager. It doesnt work. So the problem is not the code. Its just the way that QFRame cant be displayed on QFrame. Anyone know how to fix this??**

/************************************************PREVIOUSLY STUFFFFFFFF (IGNORE) **********************************************************/

I have a class from QWidget class, but I want to add a list of 5 widgets into that top level widget.

When I add them they seem to overlap, even if I arranged them in a horizontal layout.

Is there some parameter I m not setting or missing anything?

The picture has 5 widget spaces and at runtime I create the widgets and fill them. But when I do they get crowded at left for some reason.

```
sensor1 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor2 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor3 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor4 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor5 = new LightWidget(green, this);
```

Here is the output.. Instead of seeing 5 green circles I see all of them at left on top of other.

[image]

Cheers,
Nick

This is the UI form code... on request...

```
void setupUi(QWidget *Form)
{
    if (Form->objectName().isEmpty())
        Form->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Form"));
    Form->resize(762, 150);
    QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    Form->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    Form->setMinimumSize(QSize(700, 150));
    Form->setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 150));
    layoutWidget = new QWidget(Form);
    layoutWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("layoutWidget"));
    layoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(10, 20, 721, 101));
    layout = new QHBoxLayout(layoutWidget);
    layout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("layout"));
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    dataLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    dataLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("dataLayout"));
    posLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    posLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("posLayout"));
    posLabel = new QLabel(layoutWidget);
    posLabel->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("posLabel"));

    posLayout->addWidget(posLabel);

    posValue = new QLabel(layoutWidget);
    posValue->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("posValue"));
    posValue->setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215));

    posLayout->addWidget(posValue);


    dataLayout->addLayout(posLayout);

    speedLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    speedLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("speedLayout"));
    speedLabel = new QLabel(layoutWidget);
    speedLabel->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("speedLabel"));

    speedLayout->addWidget(speedLabel);

    speedValue = new QLabel(layoutWidget);
    speedValue->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("speedValue"));

    speedLayout->addWidget(speedValue);


    dataLayout->addLayout(speedLayout);

    angleLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    angleLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("angleLayout"));
    angleLabel = new QLabel(layoutWidget);
    angleLabel->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("angleLabel"));

    angleLayout->addWidget(angleLabel);

    angleValue = new QLabel(layoutWidget);
    angleValue->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("angleValue"));

    angleLayout->addWidget(angleValue);


    dataLayout->addLayout(angleLayout);


    layout->addLayout(dataLayout);

    sensorLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    sensorLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("sensorLayout"));
    sensor1 = new LightWidget(layoutWidget);
    sensor1->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("sensor1"));
    sensor1->setEnabled(true);

    sensorLayout->addWidget(sensor1);

    sensor2 = new LightWidget(layoutWidget);
    sensor2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("sensor2"));

    sensorLayout->addWidget(sensor2);

    sensor3 = new LightWidget(layoutWidget);
    sensor3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("sensor3"));

    sensorLayout->addWidget(sensor3);

    sensor4 = new LightWidget(layoutWidget);
    sensor4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("sensor4"));

    sensorLayout->addWidget(sensor4);

    sensor5 = new LightWidget(layoutWidget);
    sensor5->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("sensor5"));

    sensorLayout->addWidget(sensor5);


    layout->addLayout(sensorLayout);


    retranslateUi(Form);

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Form);
} // setupUi
```

The widgets I m adding are of QFrame type.

Comment: There's not a lot of info to go with there. Code, screenshots?

Comment: Ok I put code and gui outputs.. Thanks!

Comment: Where and how are the sensor[1-5] variables declared?

Comment: they are in the ui form. The 5 boxes in the gui are from the ui form. I m extending the gui form and adding the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just that **QFRAME CANT BE INSERTED ONTO QWIDGET**.

I changed my QFRAME to QWIDGET and it works fine. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to add the widgets in the layout shown on the right of your form (red rectangle to the right in displaypanel.ui. First determine what the layout is called by clicking on the red rectangle in UI designer and looking at the property inspector. I'll guess it's called horizontalLayout.

You can access this layout from your code and add them there something like this, assuming you have a Ui::yourform object in the class you are doing this in.

```
sensor1 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor2 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor3 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor4 = new LightWidget(green, this);
sensor5 = new LightWidget(green, this);
this->ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(sensor1);
this->ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(sensor2);
this->ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(sensor3);
this->ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(sensor4);
this->ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(sensor5);
```

An alternative way to do this would be add them to your form as widgets, then promote the widgets to type LightWidget : take a look [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Comment: I tried to promote and do this, but this time I dont even see the widgets, not even overlapped. I think they are hiding. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using promotion, you shouldn't need your code that calls `new LightWidget()` - the code generated from the UI compiler will do that. Note it will call a default constructor like `new LightWidget(QObject *parent)` without passing in green as you do here - so you may need to set the colour somewhere else.

Comment: I did that too and they are just not appearing on the frame now for some reason. Really weird.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call

```
layout->addWidget(...)
```

for each child widget where

```
layout = new QSomethingLayout(parent)
```

Comment: but the ui doesnt it already take care of it? sensor1, 2, ... are all widgets added to gui. I m just initializing the widgets with LightWidgets here.

Comment: if you create widgets in _your_ code, not code, generated by designer, _you_ should do this

Comment: I tried this. I still get the same result. I see them overlapping :(

Comment: The modified code is same as your code but posted the ui form code aswell.